# How to create an equally spaced grid of a diamond shaped area

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop, continue

I am trying to construct an equally spaced grid of points within an area that resembles an irregular diamond or rhombus. The border of this diamond is given by the following lists:

```py
xlim = list(np.linspace(0,1/4*(np.sqrt(3)+1), num=56)) + list(np.linspace(1/4*(np.sqrt(3)+1),np.sqrt(3)/2, num=20)) + \
list(np.linspace(np.sqrt(3)/2, 1/4*(np.sqrt(3)+1), num=20)) + list(np.linspace( 1/4*(np.sqrt(3)+1),0, num=56))

ylim = list(np.linspace(0, np.sqrt(3)/4, num=56)) + list(np.linspace(np.sqrt(3)/4,0, num=20)) +\
list(np.linspace(0, -np.sqrt(3)/4,num=20)) + list(np.linspace(-np.sqrt(3)/4,0, num=56))
```

Then I created `border` list that holds a tuple with the coordinates of the perimeter:

```py
border = []

for i in range(len(xlim)):
    border.append((xlim[i],ylim[i]))
```

You can check that by plotting the `xlim` and `ylim` arrays we get the polygon shape below
[image: here].

I am trying to create an equally spaced grid inside of this polygon and including the borders and this is what I have done so far:

```py
width = np.linspace(0,np.sqrt(3)/2,20)
kgrid = []

for i in range(0,len(width)):
    for j in range(0,len(width)):
        
        x = width[i]
        y = width[j]
        
        if (x,y) in border:
            
            continue
            
        else:
            kgrid.append([x,y])
```

`Kgrid` would be my resulting list with the tuples of the x and y coordinates of the equally spaced dots, however, I get the entire square of length and width sqrt(3)/2 instead of the grid within the diamond only.

I am not entirely sure what I am doing wrong so any instruction or tips towards the right direction is going to be helpful for me.

EDIT:

Testing out the distance between consecutive intersections or points of Mozway's grid.

Having saved the points in lists:

```py
for x, y in zip(X, Y):
    xs = np.linspace(*x,n1)
    ys = np.linspace(*y,n1)
    
    kx.append(xs)
    ky.append(ys)
        
    ax.plot(xs, ys, c='k', ls='', marker='.')
    plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
```

Herein kx and ky, I can flatten these two to obtain the coordinates of the grid:

```py
kx = np.array(kx).flatten()
ky = np.array(ky).flatten()
```

When I test the distance between (kx,ky) pairs (i.e kx[0],ky[0] and kx[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZQhn.png), ky[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZQhn.png)), when the loop approaches the length of (kx) in iterations,the distance between consecutive points (kx,ky) decreases. See here:

```py
dist = []

for i in range(len(kx)-1):
    
    dist.append(np.sqrt((kx[i]-kx[i+1])**2 + (ky[i]-ky[i+1])**2))
```

Checking the output of ``dist``` I see that for several iterations I get the  approximate same distance but throughout the whole lifetime of the loop this is not the case.

Check output for example.

```
...0.049274092704200266,
 0.049274092704200266,
 0.04927409270420008,
 0.04927409270420032,
 0.049274092704200266,
 0.04927409270420008,
 0.04927409270420021,
 0.04927409270420008,
 2.045339229827365,
 0.04868407742479125,
 0.04868407742479123,
 0.04868407742479123,
 0.04868407742479125,
 0.04868407742479125,
 0.048684077424791194,
 0.04868407742479126,
 0.04868407742479124,
 0.04868407742479124,
 0.048684077424791215,
 0.0486840774247913,
 0.048684077424791104,
 0.048684077424791306,
 0.04868407742479132,
 0.0486840774247913,
 0.048684077424791104,
....
```

EDIT 2:

A reference picture for Mozway. Shown in the figure below is half the area of the grid. The equally spaced points would be the blue ones, but I should be able to control how many points are inside of the grid, and thus how sparse the points are.

[![the figure below][2]][2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach would be to get a gird covering your diamond and then remove the points outside of it.

First I put your points in an array and calculate the center

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import functools

arr = np.array([[ 0.       ,  0.       ],
                [ 0.6830127, -0.4330127],
                [ 0.8660254,  0.       ],
                [ 0.6830127,  0.4330127],
                [ 0.       ,  0.       ]
               ])

center = np.mean(arr, axis=0)
```

Now I create a grid covering the diamond.

```
x = np.arange(min(arr[:,0]), max(arr[:,0])+0.04, 0.04)
y = np.arange(min(arr[:,1]), max(arr[:,1])+0.04, 0.04)
a,b = np.meshgrid(x,y)
points = np.stack([a.reshape(-1),b.reshape(-1)]).T
```

And finally I filter by being inside your diamond using the typical numpy approach of masking. That means I first create a true/false array being true where the points are that I want to keep and false otherwise and then apply it to the points.

```
def normal(a,b):
    v = b-a
    n = np.array([v[1], -v[0]])
    #normal needs to point out
    if (center-a)@n > 0:
         n *= -1
    return n

mask = functools.reduce(np.logical_and, [((points-a)@normal(a, b)) < 0 for a,b in zip(arr[:-1], arr[1:])])
plt.plot(arr[:,0],arr[:,1])
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
plt.scatter(points[mask][:,0], points[mask][:,1])
```

[image: diamond gird]

Obviously your points are given as `points[mask]`.

### Calculate difference between points to check if distance is constant

Well just shift the points by 1 and do minus like this:

```
points[mask][1:]-points[mask][:-1]
```

and you'll get

```
array([[ 0.04,  0.  ],
       [-0.12,  0.04],
       [ 0.04,  0.  ],
       [ 0.04,  0.  ],
       [ 0.04,  0.  ],
       [-0.16,  0.04],
       [ 0.04,  0.  ],
       [ 0.04,  0.  ],
       [ 0.04,  0.  ],
       [ 0.04,  0.  ],
       [ 0.04,  0.  ],
       [-0.28,  0.04],
       [ 0.04,  0.  ],
       [ 0.04,  0.  ],
       [ 0.04,  0.  ],
       [ 0.04,  0.  ],
       [ 0.04,  0.  ],
       [ 0.04,  0.  ],
       [ 0.04,  0.  ],
       [-0.32,  0.04],
...
       [-0.12,  0.04],
       [ 0.04,  0.  ],
       [ 0.04,  0.  ],
       [ 0.  ,  0.04]])
```

It starts from the bottom left goes 0.04 to the right (in x direction), then goes up by 0.04 (in y direction) and 0.12 (3 steps of 0.04) to the left (in negative x direction) and so on.

This is btw. not very surprising since I chose it that way in this line:

```
x = np.arange(min(arr[:,0]), max(arr[:,0])+0.04, 0.04)
```

I posted the differences since that seemed more understandable. But you could get the actual distances with

```
np.linalg.norm(points[mask][1:]-points[mask][:-1], axis=1)
```

Comment: With this algorithm it seems that the distance between two consecutive points might not be the same. How can I check if they are/aren't?

Comment: @Madlad oh interesting it does look like they aren't. The reason for that is that `matplotlib` does not choose an equal aspect ratio. I will edit it and post a picture with equal aspect ratio.

Comment: Oh wow! Yes I forgot about matplotlib's aspect ratio. Thank you for noticing this! And thank you for your answer I am implementing it as well :D

Comment: @Madlad No problem. You're welcome.

Comment: I am still trying to understand how I would obtain the distance between two consecutive grid points. I am not sure how the grid points here are arranged.

Comment: @Madlad I added something on it. Check it out.

Comment: Thanks @user2640045. I had done the for-loop for the distances and I didn't understand what I was getting but you explained it perfectly. Thank you a lot!

Comment: @Madlad I am glad I could help.

Comment: One more question user. For the problem I am solving, it is quite important to include grid points along the perimeter of the diamond. In your algorithm there are only some included. Do you think I should just add the border of points with the spacing mentioned above?

Comment: @Madlad Hmm is the shape of the diamond fix? Maybe you could make it so the slope of the upper and lower line of the diamond are 1 and -1 and the grid step size divides the distance between them. Then it would perfectly work out.

Comment: The shape of the diamond is fixed and bounded by the coordinates you put in the beginning. Mmm I am not sure how to do that, but I'll think about it.

Comment: @Madlad good luck

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you want to get a grid of lines joining the opposite sides.

For this you can keep the coordinates of the four sides separate and join the evenly spaced points using loops:

```
n1 = 10 # number of blue -> green linew
n2 = 20 # number of orange -> red lines

faces = [ # blue
         (np.linspace(0,1/4*(np.sqrt(3)+1), num=n1), np.linspace(0, np.sqrt(3)/4, num=n1)),
          # orange
         (np.linspace(1/4*(np.sqrt(3)+1),np.sqrt(3)/2, num=n2), np.linspace(np.sqrt(3)/4,0, num=n2)),
          # green
         (np.linspace(np.sqrt(3)/2, 1/4*(np.sqrt(3)+1), num=n1), np.linspace(0, -np.sqrt(3)/4,num=n1)),
          # red
         (np.linspace( 1/4*(np.sqrt(3)+1),0, num=n2), np.linspace(-np.sqrt(3)/4,0, num=n2)),
        ]

ax = plt.subplot()
for face in faces:
    ax.plot(face[0], face[1])

for i in range(2):
    x1 = faces[i][0]
    x2 = faces[i+2][0][::-1]
    y1 = faces[i][1]
    y2 = faces[i+2][1][::-1]
    
    X = list(zip(x1, x2))
    Y = list(zip(y1, y2))
    
    for x, y in zip(X, Y):
        ax.plot(x, y, c='k', ls=':')
```

[image: grid on diamond]

#### same with points:

```
n1 = 10
n2 = 20

faces = [(np.linspace(0,1/4*(np.sqrt(3)+1), num=n1), np.linspace(0, np.sqrt(3)/4, num=n1)),
         (np.linspace(1/4*(np.sqrt(3)+1),np.sqrt(3)/2, num=n2), np.linspace(np.sqrt(3)/4,0, num=n2)),
         (np.linspace(np.sqrt(3)/2, 1/4*(np.sqrt(3)+1), num=n1), np.linspace(0, -np.sqrt(3)/4,num=n1)),
         (np.linspace( 1/4*(np.sqrt(3)+1),0, num=n2), np.linspace(-np.sqrt(3)/4,0, num=n2)),
        ]

ax = plt.subplot()
for face in faces:
    ax.plot(face[0], face[1])

i = 0
    
x1 = faces[i][0]
x2 = faces[i+2][0][::-1]
y1 = faces[i][1]
y2 = faces[i+2][1][::-1]
    
X = list(zip(x1, x2))
Y = list(zip(y1, y2))

for x, y in zip(X, Y):
    xs = np.linspace(*x, num=20)
    ys = np.linspace(*y, num=20)
    ax.plot(xs, ys, c='k', ls='', marker='.')
```

[image: grid intersection]

same with `n1 = 20` and `n2 = 20`:

[image: intersections, 20x20]

Comment: Basically yes. I want to store the (x,y) coordinates of the intersections of the lines that join the opposite sides.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the first for loop. I think in this place you are joining the two opposite faces but I am not sure how?

Comment: in the list face with index 0 and face with index 2 are opposed, same with 1 and 3, so I just loop twice, once for 0/2, once for 1/3

Comment: How can I ensure that the grids are indeed equidistant? @mozway

Comment: `linspace` takes care of it for you

Comment: Thanks! Also I am sorry if this is a trivial question but if I would like to save all the intersections would I just need to save all x,y instances as it is in your code?

Comment: I added an alternative to get the intersections (you would need to save the `xs` and `ys` in the last block)

Comment: NB. I used here two different spacings for the two dimensions, but of course you can use the same for both

Comment: Yeah I think that to get the same type of spacing, since one of the sides measures sqrt(3)/2 and the other is 1/2, I do the respective ratio and that is how I get totally equidistant points all throughout the polygon including the sides.

Comment: Thank you Mozway I just checked with a good old distance formula check and the points are actually equidistant. Just wanted to make sure! Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: I was checking this today again and actually I get tiny increments in spacing between the points as it goes from left to right, thus linspace actually does not guarantee for the intersections to be equally spaced. How can I fix this?

Comment: @Madlad I am not sure I get you. Yes [`linspace`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) does give evenly spaced values. From the docs: *Return evenly spaced numbers over a specified interval.* It is possible however that the resolution of the images makes the display not perfect. Can you explain in more details what you expect? Maybe provide a schematic?

Comment: Yes I know that linspace itself gives evenly spaced values. Now I don't think that translates to *evenly spaced grid points* within the diamond shaped perimeter. For example, see the point distribution in face 0 compared to the point distribution in face 1. I didn't just judge by the looks of the plot, I calculated the resulting distance of each point in the grid with its consecutive point, and I don't get the same spacing all throughout.

Comment: Can you provide a schematic of what you expect? The points are evenly space on their imaginary lines (you told me in the first comment "*I want to store the (x,y) coordinates of the intersections of the lines that join the opposite sides*"), they are **not** evenly spaced in diagonal or other dimensions, if this is what you mean

Comment: I added a figure. Apologies for the back and forth.

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification, then isn't @user2640045's answer fitting your needs?